# Powershell "'get-error' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Get-Error should be one of the basic PS commands, but it doesn't work for me.
I get an error:

```
get-error : The term 'get-error' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I updated the module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.
I've checked the list of commands in it with:

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

And it is still not there.

Does anyone know how to fix it or how to get detailed error info without it?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that? (it isn't, btw)

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: The docs are a bit misleading, `Get-Error` is available in PS Core as of `v7.2.3`, according to MS Docs, this cmdlet is part of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` in the `v5.1` but it's not actually there hehe

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - When I look at MSDocs for 5.1, it says "Nope, not available; here's the newest version in which it is available."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin oh my, you're right, I didn't notice that banner! Ok well makes total sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell errors are objects, just like everything else. As such, you can interrogate their properties and invoke their methods. They’re documented on MSDocs as [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord).

When I forced an error, and looked at the object with `Get-Member`, I saw

```
PS D:\Scripts> $error[0] | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord

Name                  MemberType     Definition
----                  ----------     ----------
Equals                Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode           Method         int GetHashCode()
GetObjectData         Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System....
GetType               Method         type GetType()
ToString              Method         string ToString()
CategoryInfo          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategoryInfo CategoryInfo {get;}
ErrorDetails          Property       System.Management.Automation.ErrorDetails ErrorDetails {get;set;}
Exception             Property       System.Exception Exception {get;}
FullyQualifiedErrorId Property       string FullyQualifiedErrorId {get;}
InvocationInfo        Property       System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo InvocationInfo {get;}
PipelineIterationInfo Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[int] PipelineIterationInfo {g...
ScriptStackTrace      Property       string ScriptStackTrace {get;}
TargetObject          Property       System.Object TargetObject {get;}
PSMessageDetails      ScriptProperty System.Object PSMessageDetails {get=& { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.Except...


PS D:\Scripts>
```

but using the MSDocs will give you more *useful* information.